# java boolean overloaded set method

Tags: java, methods, set, boolean

my teacher gave me this assignment and I have the whole program working flawlessly but I don't understand the part on step 4 where he wants me to overload the set method to set the declawed value. In the program I am asking a true of false question and using a set method in the Cat class to set the Boolean value.  Why would I need a overload method for that? If anyone can offer some thought on the subject that would be awesome. Thanks!

```
1.Create a new class called Cat that includes the functionality below

2.The new class has the attributes of:
name – type String
age – type integer
weight – type double
breed - type String
declawed - type boolean - true for has no claws, false for has claws

3.  Be sure your classes have a reasonable complement of constructor, accessor and 
mutator methods. Every member variable must have at least one independent accessor and 
one independent mutator.

 4. Example:
    public void setName(String name) mutator used to set name
    public void setBreed(String breed) mutator used to set the breed
    public void set(Boolean declawed) used to set claws or not
    ***(You must overload the set method to set deClawed value)**** 
    public String getName() accessor used to get name
    public String getBreed() accessor used to get breed
    public boolean getBoolean() access used to get the value of declawed
```

Here is the proper output.

Example Run:
Enter the name of Cat 1: Sam

Enter the age of Cat 1: 1

Enter the weight of Cat 1: 5

Enter the breed of Cat 1: fluffy1

Does the cat have claws? True or False?: True

Answer (score 0):

You're right, that makes no sense.

In Java, [overloading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) a method means to define it multiple times with the same name but a different *method signature*.

An example of overloading the `set()` method would look something like this:

```
public void set(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
public void set(Boolean declawed) {
    this.declawed = declawed;
}
```

You don't seem to have any such requirement, and in any case it makes no sense to overload mutator methods, since Java has a naming convention that you call your methods `setFoo()` and `setBar()` to set the values of variables named `foo` and `bar`.

Perhaps your Professor meant that you must *implement* the set method?

In any case, even if your program is working without error, it's worth your time to talk to your teacher to ask them to clarify the program requirements.

Comment: I'm assuming that there is another set method somewhere in his skeleton code that we haven't been shown. That, or a dumb professor (no disrespect, of course).

Answer (score 0):

I guess its just for the practice.

But technically boolean!=Boolean

There's not much difference but wrapper types accepts null values so Boolean is handy ie. if You are using Your set method for data read from database from column which allows null values.

Primitive boolean uses less memory.

Try this code:

```
public class Cat {
boolean declawed;
public void set(boolean declawed){
    System.out.println("boolean called");
    this.declawed=declawed;
}
public void set(Boolean declawed){
    System.out.println("Boolean called");
 //   if(declawed==null){declawed=false;}
    this.declawed=declawed;
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat c=new Cat();
        c.set(Boolean.TRUE);
        c.set(true);
        c.set(null);
    }
}
```